# Silverlight Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am making a `stored procedure call` with two parameters using `IDataReader`. When I am trying to read the values, it throws me `Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed.` error. Neither I'm `closing the connection` nor using `using`. I am not sure why I am getting this error. In `immediate window` I don't see `reader.HasRows` property but when I am debugging, I can see the results while making a call but when I want to read it, it throws error.

Code:

```
public bool UniqueColumnValuesCheckCall(ObservableCollection<String> selectedColumns, String selectedTableName)
{
    bool uniqueValueExists = true;
    String columns = String.Empty;
    String result = String.Empty;

    if (selectedColumns != null && selectedColumns.Count > 0)
        columns = String.Join(", ", selectedColumns);

    int commandTimeout = GetSQLCommandTimeOut();
    IDataParameter[] parameters = 
    {   
        this.Helper.GetParameter("@columnName", columns),
        this.Helper.GetParameter("@tableName", selectedTableName)
    };

    //I can see results while debugging.
    IDataReader reader = this.Helper.WithCommandTimeout(commandTimeout).ExecuteReader(this.ConnectionString, "IX_FindUniqueColumnValues", parameters);

    try
    {
        while (reader.Read()) // For some reason it throws error "Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed." here
        {
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                result = reader.GetString(0);

            if (result.Equals("Selected columns have no unique values"))
                uniqueValueExists = false;
            else
                uniqueValueExists = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return uniqueValueExists;
}
```

Comment: How long is your timeout?

Comment: What is your code for this.Helper.WithCommandTimeout?

Comment: Perhaps you have some database connectivity issues which is causing your reader to close prematurely?

Comment: @user6150 I thought so but I'm using exact same connection in another stored proc call and it is working perfectly fine. I am wondering what is so special about this call. That's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: Does it throw that Invalid error the first time or at some random Read() call?

Comment: @user6150 whenever 'm trying to call this stored proc